# getting docker swarm cluster worker node error

Tags: docker, swarm

I'm working on docker swarm. When I connect to a worker node I get this error:

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the
>   connection is unavailable

I have already stopped firewall and setenforce 0. What could be the problem?

Comment: What command are you executing? You have add more details to your question. Add more details on your setup

Comment: Tarun Lalwani :- actually i initialized docker swarm at system 1 by this command (docker swarm init --advertise-addr "IP") . swarm started . and worker node side i'm putting the command (add worker node) . at worker node side i'm getting this error

Comment: and my this problem is solved by reinstalling docker-engine. now i'm getting new error (Error response from daemon: error while validating Root CA Certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid) while adding worker node

Comment: use `docker swarm leave` on master node and reinstall docker on master also and then use `docker swarm init` again

Comment: i have tried this lot's of time ..,but always getiing same error or other error .

Comment: Are you using proxy or VPN on any of the systems?

Comment: no i'm not using any proxy or VPN. i just have 4 machine in my VM .i'm trying over the VM

Comment: Check `date` on both systems, they should be same else you get SSL errors

Comment: date and time both are same....in all VM

Comment: What adapters are all the VM using? Attached screenshot of the adapter settings of the two VM in question

Comment: i'm using at bridge mode. all VM's

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VM then you can init docker swarm with alternative IP Address using docker  "swarm init --advertise-addr :"

**Example:** docker swarm init --advertise-addr 192.168.99.100:2377
and then add the nodes to the swarm.

**Example:** docker swarm join --token  --advertise-addr :
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-RANDOMTOKEN 192.168.99.100:2377

Some people say that it works only with 2377 port.

Check yourself if it works for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the `swarm init --advertise-addr <some ip>`.Then you will get the join token but when I am going to add new swarm to the manager as a worker then i am getting the same error node is already part of swarm.
So take care while using vm ip address. It should be different from and exact match to the manager ip.

Comment: actually there is two ip exists in your system. type "ifconfig" command